# org.xnio.BrokenPipeException: Remote side closed the message stream intermittently exception in wildfly-9.0.1.Final causes deadlock

Tags: ejb, deadlock, lookup

We are using wildfly-9.0.1.Final.EJB lookup throws following exception which causes Java-level deadlock.Can any one help me on this regard?

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Below error found in thread dump

```
Found one Java-level deadlock:

"EJB default - 357":
waiting to lock monitor 0x000000004913dc18 (object 0x00000003455a4c60, a java.util.ArrayDeque),
which is held by "default I/O-27"
"default I/O-27":
waiting to lock monitor 0x000000004939bc28 (object 0x00000007a8f4d608, a org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream),
which is held by "EJB default - 357"
```

Below error found in application logs.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 357) WFLYEJB0150: Could not write method invocation failure for method public abstract java.util.HashMap com.example..bizlogic.ejbs.testejb.getFolderPaths(int,java.lang.String,int) throws java.rmi.RemoteException on bean named test for appname test-ear modulename test-ejb distinctname due to: org.xnio.BrokenPipeException: Remote side closed the message stream
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.OutboundMessage$1.accept(OutboundMessage.java:124)
at org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream.send(BufferPipeOutputStream.java:122)
at org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream.send(BufferPipeOutputStream.java:110)
at org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream.getBuffer(BufferPipeOutputStream.java:74)
at org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream.write(BufferPipeOutputStream.java:92)
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.OutboundMessage.write(OutboundMessage.java:272)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
.............
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
in field folderPath
in object java.util.HashMap@64c7abb6
```